# Windows 8.1 doesn't remember which system icons are on and off

Tags: windows-8.1

After updating to Windows 8.1, the settings I choose for which system icons are on and off don't seem to be remembered. In particular, I turn "Input Indicator" off but after each restart it comes back.

Is there a way to get these settings persistent again?